# List of all pre-installed 14.10 themes?

Tags: 14.10, themes

I need to know the entire list of pre-installed themes in Ubuntu 14.10. I need to remove the ones that aren't included in a clean installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That would `Ambiance` and `Radiance`, along with a `HighContrast` accessibility theme. The first two are provided by the `light-themes` package, a dependency of the [`ubuntu-artwork`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-artwork) package which brings in the default themes, wallpapers and other art.

Comment: Thanks.:D One more question: If I deleted the themes I installed, and one is in use, what would happen?